# UIFeedbackGenerator object creation crashes on iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, iphone-6, uifeedbackgenerator

Has anyone else encountered this? Specifically with an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.0 I'm getting consistent reports of the following crashing:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
}
```

Where it's not even being used, just created and it causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash. The docs say it just fails silently if the device doesn't support it. Oddly enough if I change the check to `iOS 10.0.1` it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Weird, it's silently failing for me on a 6s. Try cleaning your project?

Comment: @Jordan It fails silently for me on a 6s as well, but not a 6. Cleaned.

Comment: Also seeing this, only on 10.0.0 (14A5345a)

Comment: Also see a single crash on 10.0.0 (14A5309d) for iPhone 5s in production users.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few seemingly random crashes in production when calling this function as well.  When reviewing some old logs, I found that this was only occurring on iOS 10.0.0.  As users updated past that, I stopped seeing the crash.  I imagine it was some sort of internal UIKit bug that was fixed in iOS 10.0.1.